# Derivative of a composite function with respect to a matrix

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, non-convex-optimization

I would like some hints on how to derive the following function with respect to the matrix $X$:

$$ f(X)=\left\| y - \sum_k (h_k X^k)x \right\|_2^2$$

where $X$ is a matrix, $x$ and $y$ are two given vectors and $h_k$ is a (given) scalar coefficient that weights the matrix. This is the composition of a convex function (the norm) with a non affine function. I want to linearize the function with respect to X, so I would like to compute the derivative. Some hints?

Thank you.

Comment: What you have written is a function of $y, x$, and $\{h_k\}$. But it is not a function of $X$, since $X$ is a dummy variable in the expression. Did you perhaps mean $\min_x$ instead?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I edited the question by explaining what each variable represents. All is given except the matrix $X$, which is the optimization variable. So the function is $f(X)$

Comment: If you are talking about $f(X)$, why did you put an extraneous "$\min_X$ in front? It serves no purpose except to seriously obfuscate.

Comment: @PaulSinclair you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a convention where a greek letter denotes a scalar, lowercase latin a vector, and uppercase latin a matrix. So replace your original variable names with
$$\eqalign{
\alpha_k = h_k 
,\qquad 
\phi(X) = f(X) 
,\qquad 
x = z 
}$$
and define two new matrices which will be used later
$$\eqalign{
P &= \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_kX^k \\
M &= 2z(Pz-y)^T\\
}$$
Let's also use a colon to denote the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
Write the objective function in terms of the above definitions.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (Pz-y):(Pz-y) \\
d\phi &= 2(Pz-y):dP\,z \\
  &= 2(Pz-y)z^T:dP \\
  &= M^T:\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} X^jdX\,X^{k-j-1} \\
  &= \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\alpha_kX^jMX^{k-j-1}\right)^T:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
  &= \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\alpha_kX^jMX^{k-j-1}\right)^T \\
}$$

Comment: How do you find the explicit $dP$ in the third equation of $d \phi$?

Comment: Here's a small concrete example
$$\eqalign{
dX^3 &= d(X\cdot X\cdot X) \\
 &= dX\cdot X^2 + X\cdot dX\cdot X + X^2\cdot dX
}$$
Generalizing this result to $dX^k\,$ (and then to the polynomial) yields the given expression.

Comment: I miss this property that should be basic indeed. How do you expand the second equality?

Comment: Consider the product of two rectangular matrices $\,P=AB$. How would you calculate $dP$?  Now apply that idea (repeatedly) to the polynomial of a square matrix like $X$.  If you assume that $dX$ and $X$ commute, then $\,dX^3 = 3X^2dX\,$ just like the scalar case ...but they **don't** commute. Working through a rectangular example like $P$ will drive that point home.

Comment: So, for $dP$ you mean the differential of $P$, if I am right. In such case, I am used to define differential of a scalar function, not a vector/matrix function. Anyway, what you are saying is to express the matrix differential $dP$ as the product of its gradient and its "independent" increment $dP$. Can I start from $P+dP=(A+dA)(B+dB)= AB + dAB + AdB + dAdB$. The differential is $dAB + AdB$ right? What would be the gradient? Should I divide for $dAdB?$

Comment: Okay, now you understand how to calculate $dX^3$ and how the third equation of $d\phi$ was obtained -- that was the point of the example. Note that the _differential_ $(dP)$ is a matrix, but the _gradient_ $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial A}\right)$ is a fourth-order tensor. If you ever find yourself trying to calculate such higher-order tensors, you should stop and come up with a better approach, which does not require them.

Comment: Correct, but what would be the "independent" variable you would divide the differential for? Is $\partial A$ or $\partial B$?(I guess both).
As a side note, I guess that the notation $dX^3$ is misleading: would be more correct to write $d(X^3)$. Correct? Otherwise you may easily find that $dX^3= something + dX^3$

Comment: There are two gradients, one for each variable. To find the gradient wrt $A$ set $dB=0.\,$ What remains to the left of $\,":dA"\,$ is the gradient. To find the gradient wrt $B$ set $dA=0$. You can think of it as division, but it's a very special kind of division. And yes, one should put parentheses around all expressions, but transposes, complex conjugates and simple powers are relatively unambiguous: $\,dP^3 = d(P\cdot P\cdot P)\;$

Comment: Thank you, very clear.

Comment: A last question: when you talk about special kind of division, what are you referring to? 
For instance, consider the vector valued function $f(x)=Ax$. Then $f(x+dx)= f(x)+ Adx$. So we should divide for $dx$. But it would not be correct, because we need $A^\top$. What is the correct division?

Comment: Consider the differential expression $$df = g\;dx$$If $g$ is a scalar then it is a gradient only if $x$ is a scalar. If $x$ is a vector then the gradient is $g$ multiplied by the identity matrix $I$, but if $x$ is a matrix then the gradient is $g$ multiplied by the 4th order identity tensor $\cal E$. In the case that $g$ is a matrix then it is a gradient only if $x$ is a vector. If $g$ is a row vector and $x$ is a column vector then $g^T$ is the gradient. So you can't simply move $dx$ to the LHS (aka _divide by_ $dx$) and assume that $g$ will be the gradient of $f$.

Comment: You are not making assumptions on the dimension of $f$ itself though. If $g$ is a matrix then it is a gradient also if $x$ is a matrix and the function is scalar. Could you please expand more your comment? I was going to say that "the gradient is the element in the inner product with the differential $dx$", but it would not be correct I guess because $Adx $ is not an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to linearize $f(X)$ *around $X= 0$*, this is easily accomplished

$$f(X) =\left(y - \sum_k h_k X^kx\right)^T\left(y - \sum_k h_k X^kx\right)\\
=\left(y^T - \sum_k h_kx^T(X^T)^k\right)^T\left(y - \sum_k h_k X^kx\right)\\
=y^Ty - \sum_k h_ky^TX^kx - \sum_k h_kx^T(X^T)^ky + \sum_j\sum_k h_jh_k x^T(X^T)^jX^kx\\
= y^Ty + h_0^2x^Tx - h_0(y^Tx + x^Ty) - h_1(y^TXx + x^TX^Ty) + 2h_0h_1x^TXx + O(X^2)$$

Linearization just means ignoring higher order terms, so the linearization for $X$ near $0$ is $$y^Ty + h_0^2x^Tx - h_0(y^Tx + x^Ty) - h_1(y^TXx + x^TX^Ty) + 2h_0h_1x^TXx$$
If there are no terms for $k = 0$, it simplifies to
$$y^Ty - h_1(y^TXx + x^TX^Ty)$$